# Remover evento oyente de una clase no funciona

Tags: javascript, html5, eventos

```
class FileManager{

    addResourceRecycleOperation(){
        const actualRecyclerButtons = document.querySelectorAll(
            ".resourcePreviewFrame > ion-icon[name = 'close-outline']"
        );

        for(let i = 0; i < actualRecyclerButtons.length; i++){
            //Aquí se añade el evento oyente
            actualRecyclerButtons[i].addEventListener("click", this.confirmDiscardResource);
        }
    }

    confirmDiscardResource(ev){

        const value = confirm("¿Realmente deseas quitar este elemento de la lista de carga?");
        //Aquí se intenta remover el evento oyente.
        if(value) ev.currentTarget.removeEventListener("click", this.confirmDiscardResource);

    }

}
```

El metodo `addResourceRecycleOperation` se ejecuta después de que los archivos hayan sido añadidos a una cola, simplemente para añadirles un botón de eliminarlos si el usuario quiere eliminarlos de la cola, donde el elemento html se ve así:

```
<div class="resourcePreviewFrame">
     //Este es el elemento al que se le añade el click
     <ion-icon name = "close-outline"></ion-icon>
     <img src="images/buttons_images/document-icon.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Imprimí en consola `this.confirmDiscardResource` dentro del metodo `confirmDiscardResource` y el resultado es `undefined`, así que ya se lo que pasa... pero entonces como recupero el contexto para poder quitar este evento oyente?.

**Nota: ya probe bind, no funciono.**

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar arrow functions `() => {}` este tipo de funciones se añadieron en ES7 y no tienen binding local. El `this` siempre hace referencia al objeto en el que estan.

```js
class FileManager{

    addResourceRecycleOperation(){
        const actualRecyclerButtons = document.querySelectorAll(
            ".resourcePreviewFrame > [name='close-outline']"
        );

        for(let i = 0; i < actualRecyclerButtons.length; i++){
            //Aquí se añade el evento oyente
            actualRecyclerButtons[i].addEventListener("click", this.confirmDiscardResource);
        }
    }

    confirmDiscardResource = (ev) =>  {
    console.log(this.confirmDiscardResource)
        const value = confirm("¿Realmente deseas quitar este elemento de la lista de carga?");
        //Aquí se intenta remover el evento oyente.
        if(value) ev.currentTarget.removeEventListener("click", this.confirmDiscardResource);

    }

}

new FileManager().addResourceRecycleOperation();
```

```html
<div class="resourcePreviewFrame">
     <span name="close-outline">x</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias hawks, si, me funciono :3